BLE Scan for Android Automotive not finding any devices
I am currently trying to scan for BLE devices within Android Automotive which however does not return any device. BTH Classic is working fine.
I am starting the scan via mBluetoothScanner.startScan(leScanCallback). However I am suspecting that permissions is the root cause since even via the menu I am not finding any BLE devices:
    <!-- Required for Bluetooth operations -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<!-- Required for Bluetooth LE scanning -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.type.automotive"
    android:required="true" />

An important note would be that I am using an emulator for the BLE scan.

How can you perform scan tests using an emulator?

you can have several emulated devices. For bth classic it works

Please use a real device for BLE scanning instead of the emulator.
